# Unity and Xcode Build crash after Splash Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, vuforia

After updating to Unity 5.2.0f3, Xcode 6.4, and the Vuforia plugin, when I build my xcodeproj, my app just shows the Splash Screen and then crashes with the following error:

```
EXC_BADACCESS (Code=1,adress=0x94)
```

I fixed similar issues by adjusting the Player Settings in Unity several times, though it seems that there is a problem with IL2CPP / Universal Architecture.

Any master that can help?

Answer (score 0):

We have one known bug related to Vuforia and packing of a managed structure that causes alignment problems for iOS builds. I'm not sure that this is the error you are seeing. You can work around the error by disabling optimizations in the Xcode project (although this is certainly not a fix).

We're working with the Vuforia developers now to have the problem corrected.

Comment: Optimisation levels on 'None' and still crashing, I saw some comments related to Unity version (mine is 5.2), about to Architecture and Api, but no real solutions. Any more ideas? Thnxs!

Comment: No, nothing yet, sorry. We'll likely need to have the Vuforia devs correct the issue in the plugin (id this is the same issue). You can also submit a bug report to Unity if you would like, as we can have a look to confirm that it is the same.

Comment: Bug report done, now just trying with older versions of Unity 5.1.3p1.